# How interconnected can a collection asset be ? (3.5.1)

Tags: modifiers, constraints, collections, asset-browser

**Context**

I am currently working on an asset library of mechanical components and I have inconsistent results when importing "complex" collection assets into a new file.

By complex I mean that the objects of the collection have:

- modifiers referencing each others (including geometry nodes)
- constraints referencing each other (like distances constraints)
- parenting

When I try to imports those assets as collections they sometime do simply not appear or get imported with messed up relation. My main issue being that this is wildly inconsistent from asset to asset and sometime for a single asset, some work just fine while other have various strange behaviors.

**Main question being:**

What is the current support for object referencing each other in various ways in Collection Assets ?

Comment: There are no Blender developers here nor does anyone here work for the Blender Foundation so I doubt anyone here can answer that question. The only mention of instancing collections are in the Blender manual [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/asset_browser.html#using-assets) under the Tips section but that doesn't describe how they're supposed to interact. If you think you've found a potential bug,report it giving as many details as you can via Blender's Help > Report a Bug menu.